# is Sql.execute() synchronous or asynchronous with groovy?

Tags: sql, asynchronous, groovy, synchronous

I stumbled onto a bit of groovy code deleting rows from a database by batches of a given size:

```
for (int index = 0; index <= loopCnt; index++) {
    sql.execute("DELETE TOP(" + maxEntriesToDeleteAtOnce + ") FROM LoaderQueue WHERE Status = ? AND LastUpdated < ?", stateToDelete, date)
}
```

I have 0 experience with groovy, and I know that the delete statement can take a few seconds to be fully executed, even if the batch size is relatively small. I'm wondering if the execution will wait for each statement to be completed before looping , or if we might send  a few statements in parallel ? In short I'm wondering if the `sql.execute()` command is synchronous

I can't really try anything yet as there is no DEV environment for the application involved.

Comment: sql.execute is synchronous. you could try to use threading, but i bet the bottleneck is database that will block parallel deletion from the same table with the same parameters...

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!  As the sql script passed uses top(), I think it is wiser to execute sequentially. So far, the DB server encounters performance issues when deleting too many rows in a single statement.

Comment: Synchronous... the source code for Sql is here: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-sql/src/main/java/groovy/sql/Sql.java